# Converting a string to a double c++

Tags: c++, string, double, ifstream, type-conversion

This code reads the first line of some data I have in .txt file, 
this first line value is '6.0', im reading the rest of the data later on in a loop, my question is how can I convert 'line' (a string) to a double (I would call 'instances') so that I can use it later in the program? It needs to be a double so I can do some calculations later with other double types. Probably a very simple solution, thanks in advance.

NOTE: I have tried using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
double instances = atof(line.c_str());
```

But it returns 0 not the correct value '6.0'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    string line;
    ifstream infile ("data2.txt");
    if (infile.is_open())
    { 
        getline (infile,line);    
        cout << line << '\n';
        infile.close();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Youl'l apply `std::istringstream iss(line);` and read a `double` value from it: `double mydouble; iss >> mydouble;`

Comment: `atof("6.0")` definitely gives you back 6.0... Are you sure the `line` isn't like `"x6.0"` or something?

Comment: where is you output statement for the double value? You are printing out the origin line,

Answer (score 8):

You have lots of options. These all have different ways of checking the output for validity. Some of them throw an exception if `line` doesn't contain a `double`, some give a return value that you could check. Whichever one is best for you depends entirely on your program.

C++11 introduced [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof):

```
double instances = std::stod(line);
```

Before that, there's the confusingly named [`std::atof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) that still returns a `double`:

```
double instances = std::atof(line.c_str());
```

Or you could use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)'s [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) to extract a `double`:

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
double instances;
iss >> instances;
```

Or you could use [`std::sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

```
double instances;
std::sscanf(line.c_str(), "%lf", &instances);
```

Or you could use [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
double instances = boost::lexical_cast<double>(line);
```

Comment: Also, there is the boost approach: double instance = boost::lexical_cast<double>(line);

Comment: In my experience ``boost::lexical_cast`` was slow to the point of unusability.

Comment: Barry, where are you putting the -- double instances = atof(line.c_str());? I get 0 returned.

Comment: @AbbieMarsay What is your `line`? If it's `"6.0"`, `atof` [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c819cfe0d69191e8)

Comment: @AbbieMarsay Let's face it.  Your `line` does not contain a valid double.  This is the trouble of introducing variables in a question, where no one knows what's behind that variable.

Comment: @AbbieMarsay Huh? `line(string)` is not a thing.

Comment: im just stating that it is a type string to try to explain.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Lets face it, it does contain a valid double value 6.0 as I said, Barry thank you for your help, I had put double instances = atof(line.c_str()); before the getline by accident causing a 0.

Comment: @AbbieMarsay So you're saying... Paul was correct. Your `line` did not contain a valid `double`.

Comment: @Barry No I had put atof before the getline meaning I was trying to convert  line before it was read. It wasn't because line did not contain 0.6.

Comment: @AbbieMarsay ...? At the time you called `atof()`, `line` did not contain a a valid `double`.

Comment: @AbbieMarsay There is nothing wrong with `atof` if you have given it a valid double number as a string.  At the time you called `atof`, line did not contain a valid double.  Saying that line will eventually contain a valid double does not invalidate my point to you.